# Passing Value Using Intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

click Signup button it must intent signup values to Register class,then if login button pressed it must intent Login value to register class.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText main_edt_Mobile;
private EditText main_edt_Password;

private Button main_btn_Signup;
private Button main_btn_Login;

private String main_mobile;
private String main_password;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    main_edt_Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_mobile);
    main_edt_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

    main_btn_Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    main_btn_Signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);

    main_btn_Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LOGED IN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String main_mobile = main_edt_Mobile.getText().toString();
            String main_password = main_edt_Password.getText().toString();

            //Mobile
            if(main_mobile.length() == 10){

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Only 10 Digit Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String phone = String.valueOf(main_mobile);
            char c  = phone.charAt(0);
            if (c == '8' || c == '9' ||c =='7'){

            }else if( c == '0' ||c == '1' ||c == '2' ||c == '3' ||c == '4' ||c == '5' ||c == '6')
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Number Must Begin with 9 8 7",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            //Password
            if(main_password.length() <4){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Must Have Minimum 4 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else if(main_password.length()>=15){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Can Have Maximum 8 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class );

            i.putExtra("key_main_m",main_mobile);
            i.putExtra("key_main_p",main_password);
            i.putExtra("Login",true);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    main_btn_Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Opening Signup Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Signup.class );
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}}
```

Signup Activity

```
public class Signup extends Activity {

private String firstName ;
private String lastName ;
private String mobile;
private String password ;
private String email ;

private EditText edt_Signup_FirstName;
private EditText edt_Signup_LastName;
private EditText edt_Signup_Mobile;
private EditText edt_Signup_Password;
private EditText edt_Signup_Email;

private Button btn_Signup_Register;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    edt_Signup_FirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_first_name);
    edt_Signup_LastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_last_name);
    edt_Signup_Mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_mobile);
    edt_Signup_Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_password);
    edt_Signup_Email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_email);

    btn_Signup_Register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signup_register);


    btn_Signup_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firstName = edt_Signup_FirstName.getText().toString();
            String lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();
            String mobile = edt_Signup_Mobile.getText().toString();
            String password = edt_Signup_Password.getText().toString();
            String email = edt_Signup_Email.getText().toString();

            //First Name
            if(firstName.length() <8){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "First Name Must Have Minimum 8 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else if(firstName.length()>=15){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "First Name Can Have Maximum 8 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            //Last Name
            if(lastName.length() <8){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Last Name Must Have Minimum 8 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else if(lastName.length()>=15){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Last Name Can Have Maximum 15 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            //Mobile
            if(mobile.length() == 10){

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Enter Only 10 Digit Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String phone = String.valueOf(mobile);
            char c  = phone.charAt(0);
            if (c == '8' || c == '9' ||c =='7'){

            }else if( c == '0' ||c == '1' ||c == '2' ||c == '3' ||c == '4' ||c == '5' ||c == '6')
            {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Number Must Begin with 9 8 7",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            //Password
            if(password.length() <4){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Password Must Have Minimum 4 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else if(password.length()>=15){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Password Can Have Maximum 8 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            //Email
            if(email.length() <8){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Email Must Have Minimum 8 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else if(email.length()>=25){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Email Can Have Maximum 8 Character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            Intent i =new Intent(Signup.this,Register.class);

            i.putExtra("key_f",firstName);
            i.putExtra("key_l",lastName);
            i.putExtra("key_m",mobile);
            i.putExtra("key_p",password);
            i.putExtra("key_e",email);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}}
```

Register Activity

```
public class Register extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    TextView txt_FirstName,txt_LastName,txt_Mobile,txt_Password,txt_Email;

    txt_Email =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
    txt_FirstName =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_firstName);
    txt_LastName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_lastName);
    txt_Mobile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_mobile);
    txt_Password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String main_mobile = i.getStringExtra("key_main_m");
    String main_password = i.getStringExtra("key_main_p");

    String firstname = i.getStringExtra("key_f");
    String lastname = i.getStringExtra("key_l");
    String mobile = i.getStringExtra("key_m");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("key_p");
    String email = i.getStringExtra("key_e");

    if ()
    {
        txt_Password.setText("PASSWORD : " +main_password);
        txt_Mobile.setText("MOBILE : " +main_mobile);
    }else if ()
    {
        txt_Email.setText("EMAIL : " +email);
        txt_FirstName.setText("FIRSTNAME : " +firstname);
        txt_LastName.setText("LASTNAME : " +lastname);
        txt_Mobile.setText("MOBILE : " +mobile);
        txt_Password.setText("PASSWORD : " +password);
    }
}}
```

What will be the code to perform click Signup button it must intent signup values to Register class,then if login button pressed it must intent Login value to register class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Parsing values:**

MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btn;
    TextView textBox;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);  
        textBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn:
            String strTemp = "Test Test";
            textBox.setText(strTemp);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("tempstring", strTemp);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Retrieving values:**

Second.java

```
 public class Second extends Activity {

    private TextView txtTemp;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.second); 

        txtTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_temp);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String strTemp = intent.getStringExtra("tempstring");

        txtTemp.setText(strTemp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these values by using intent.putExtra from register activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class );    
i.putExtra("key_main_m",main_mobile);
i.putExtra("key_main_p",main_password);
i.putExtra("Login",true);
```

In your login activity onCreate you can get the values from the Bundle like below

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String ph = extras.getString("key_main_m");
String pass = extras.getString("key_main_p");
```

and check the value from the string and do whatever you want.